# Most efficient way of comparing two tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have two tables which will store sales figures for products. Table one holds the last 6 weeks sales figures for each product and table 2 shows the last 12 months. I need to find a way to compare these two tables to then produce a 3rd table which will contain the difference between the 2 values as column 2 as well as the products Sage code in column one. What would be the most efficient (in terms of time) way to do this as there will be a fair amount of products to compare and it will only continue to grow? The product Sage code is the key identifier here. The two tables are created as below.

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Last6WeeksProductSales') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Last6WeeksProductSales;

   CREATE TABLE #Last6WeeksProductSales
   (
        CompoundSageCode varchar(200),
        Value decimal(18,2)
   )

    INSERT INTO #Last6WeeksProductSales  
    SELECT      [SalesOrderLine].[sProductSageCode] AS [CompoundSageCode],
                SUM([SalesOrderLine].[fQtyOrdered] * [SalesOrderLine].[fPricePerUnit]) AS [Value]   
    FROM        [SalesOrderLine]
    INNER JOIN      [SalesOrder] ON (SalesOrder.iSalesOrderID = SalesOrderLine.iSalesOrderID)
    WHERE       [SalesOrder].[dOrderDateTime] > DateAdd("ww", -6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    GROUP BYsProductSageCode;

    SELECT * FROM   #Last6WeeksProductSales
    ORDER BY    CompoundSageCode;

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Last12MonthsProductSales') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Last12MonthsProductSales;

    CREATE TABLE #Last12MonthsProductSales
    (
        CompoundSageCode varchar(200),
        Value decimal(18,2)
    )

    INSERT INTO #Last12MonthsProductSales  SELECT   [SalesOrderLine].[sProductSageCode] AS [CompoundSageCode],
            SUM([SalesOrderLine].[fQtyOrdered] * [SalesOrderLine].[fPricePerUnit]) AS [Value]

    FROM    [SalesOrderLine]
    INNER JOIN [SalesOrder] ON (SalesOrder.iSalesOrderID = SalesOrderLine.iSalesOrderID)
    WHERE       [SalesOrder].[dOrderDateTime] > DateAdd(month, -12, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    GROUP BY    sProductSageCode;

    SELECT * FROM#Last12MonthsProductSales
    ORDER BY    CompoundSageCode;

    DROP TABLE #Last6WeeksProductSales;
    DROP TABLE #Last12MonthsProductSales;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "most efficient"?  Do you mean "will take the least amount of runtime to execute"?

Comment: Yes Andy. It cant be too slow as it is intended for presentation of a graph in a web application.

Comment: How fast do you expect it to run in?

Comment: Currently to pull the data for the two tables shown above it takes less than a second. I would probably be looking for sub 2-3 seconds at the very slowest. I am not sure how long I would expect it to run but the faster the better given what it is being used for. I am not sure of the best way to tackle it.

Comment: Is CompoundSageCode supposed to be a unique key in both tables?  (I wasn't sure if that was made clear by 'key identifier'.)

Comment: Rather than doing it on the fly, I would precompute values (on a nightly basis, if needed). Since it's the same result every time it'll be faster to just hand the results to the web user than perform the query every time.

Comment: Yes adam this will be the case. The compound sage code will always be unique to each row in the two tables.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use a third table, instead of using a view?

Comment: @MichaelTodd We do not really want to be adding tables or fields just to support this at this time. We would also prefer it to be a real time graph as a large sale could be made an hour from now and the graph would not reflect this if it was not calculated on the fly

Comment: @AdamMiller There is no particular reason. I am more used to thinking it terms of tables and hadn't considered a view. I am not an SQL wizard so often forget things like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a view.  That way you don't have to worry about updating your third table, and it will reflect current information.  Base the view on a basic SELECT:

SELECT sixS.CompoundSageCode,
(twelveS.value - sixS.Value ) as diffValue
FROM Last6WeeksProductSales sixS
INNER JOIN Last12MonthsProductSales twelveS ON sixS.CompoundSageCode = twelveS.CompoundSageCode

(I have not tested this code, but it should be a good starting point.)

Comment: Thank you Adam, this is a very good starting point and looks like just what I need. It seems to be very quick too.

Answer (score 0):

Computing the difference of two tables is usually done using a `FULL OUTER JOIN`. SQL Server can implement it using all three of the physical join operators. Apply reasonable indexing and it will run fine.

If you can manage it, create covering indexes on both tables that are sorted by the join key. This will result in a highly efficient merge join plan.